# How can I implement backspace?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to simulate a keyboard interface using buttons and labels...

I understand that the method:

```
stringByAppendingString:
```

allows me to append the label by a string.

The question is... I'm trying to implement a backspace button in my code...

Every time it is pressed, I'd like to be able to simulate a backspace by removing 1 character at a time. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure that's what you want, but you can use `NSString`'s `substringToIndex:`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't backspace just be treated as the removal of the last character in the string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using an `NSMutableString`, which lets you add and remove characters without creating a new string every time.

`deleteCharactersInRange:` could then delete last character when backspace is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Removing one **character** at a time is dangerous. Here's a test case for your implementation:

1. Set your label's text in code using `myLabel.text = @"\U0001F4A9";`
2. Start the app.
3. Use you custom backspace button to remove a character.
4. Type to append other characters.